# Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on a non-object in my resturant plugin file restaurants.php

Tags: errors

when ever i click on publish or save button in custom post type in wordpress it will shows above error.
I am using single database (i.e, gls) but that database share data both sites. The problem is when ever I update any restaurant post, after click publish or save draft button it give the above error.
plz help me...
here is my code

```
function save_restaurant()
{ 
    //start function save
    global $wpdb;
    global $gldb;
    global $post;

    $glpost=get_post($post->ID);

    if($post->post_type == 'page') { return; }
    else if($post->post_type == 'post') { return; }

    if($post->post_type == 'restaurant')
        {   //start post type check


            $restaurant = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM  `wp_restaurant` WHERE `post_id`='".$post->ID."'" );
            if($restaurant->post_id==$post->ID)
            { // post is exist or not

                if($_POST['gl']==1 && $restaurant->gl_postid!=0)
                { // chec for gl exit  page and gl id exit =1       !0 


                    $gldb->update('wp_posts', array( 

                    //elements
                        ), 
                    array( 'ID' => $restaurant->gl_postid ), 
                    array( 
                        //element
                        ), 
                    array( '%d' )
                    ); 

                    $wpdb->update('wp_restaurant', array(


                    ), 
                    array( 'post_ID' => $post->ID ), 
                    array( 
                        //elements
                    ), 
                    array( '%d' ) );
                }// end check for gl exit  page and gl id exit =1       !0 
                else if($_POST['gl']==1 && $restaurant->gl_postid==0)
                {// check for gl exit  page and gl id exit =0       !0 

                    $gldb->insert('wp_posts', array( 
                        //elements
                        ), 
                    array( 
                        //elements
                        )
                    ); 
                    $last = $gldb->get_row("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'wp_posts'");
                    $glid  = $last->Auto_increment-1;
                    $wpdb->update('wp_restaurant', array(
                        //elements
                    ), 
                    array( 'post_ID' => $post->ID ), 
                    array( 
                        //elements
                        ) , 
                    array( '%d' )
                    );
                }// ending check for gl exit  page and gl id s
                else if($_POST['gl']==0 && $restaurant->gl_postid!=0)
                {// check for gl exit  page and gl id exit =0       !0 

                    $gldb->update('wp_posts', array( 
                        //elements
                        ), 
                    array( 'ID' => $restaurant->gl_postid ), 
                    array( 
                        //elements
                        ), 
                    array( '%d' )
                    ); 

                    $wpdb->update('wp_restaurant', array(
                        //elements
                    ), 
                    array( 'post_ID' => $post->ID ), 
                    array( 
                        //elements
                    ), 
                    array( '%d' ) );
                }// ending check for gl exit  page and gl id exit =0        !0 
                else
                {// check for gl exit  page and gl id exit else case
                    $wpdb->update('wp_restaurant', array(
                        //elements
                    ), 
                    array( 'post_ID' => $post->ID ), 
                    array( 
                        //elements
                    ), 
                    array( '%d' ) );
                }// ending check for gl exit  page and gl id exit else case
            } // ending post exist or not
            else
            { // else case post exist

                if( $_POST['gl']==1)
                { // check for gl==1
                    $gldb->insert('wp_posts', array( 
                        //elements

                        ), 
                    array( 
                        //elements 
                        )
                    ); 
                $last = $gldb->get_row("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'wp_posts'");
                $glid  = $last->Auto_increment-1;
                $wpdb->insert('wp_restaurant', 
                    array(
                        //elements

                    ), 
                    array( 
                        //elements
                        )
                    ); 
                }// ending check for gl==1
                else
                { // checki gl else
                    $wpdb->insert('wp_restaurant', 
                    array(
                        //elements
                    ), 
                    array( 
                        //elements
                        )
                    ); 
                }// checki gl else
            }// ending else for post exist
        }// ending else case post type check
}//ending function save
```

Comment: What's the reason for using two different databases?
Another thing: Consider REMOVING your database details (username , password) from the code!!

Answer (score 0):

Put the $gldb connection right after $wpdb, like this:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( 'gls_wp874', '8nS83Pu4cy', 'gls_wp874', 'localhost' );
$gldb = new wpdb( 'gl_wpdb12', 'n7dmSl8h4P', 'gl_wpdb12', 'localhost' );
```

You can't use connection that has not been made...